# Combining two jQuery statements using this and not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am currently having to use two statements for this and I'd like to combine this into one statement if possible.

The hierarchy for the CSS is -

```
div#optionsbox1
    div.checkbox
      a.help
    div.checkbox
      a.help
```

I'd like to .addClass('readOnly') to the div.checkbox where a.help was not clicked. So if I clicked a.help in the first div.checkbox I'd like for the second div.checkbox to have the .addClass('readOnly') applied and vice versa.

Here's the current syntax that I'm using right now to accomplish this.

```
$("#optionsbox1 .checkbox").addClass('readOnly');
$(this).parent(".checkbox").removeClass('readOnly');
```

Here's the entire function -

```
$(this).click(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        if($(this).hasClass('readOnly')){
            $(this).removeClass('readOnly');
        }
        $("#optionsbox1 :checkbox").not(this).prop('checked',false);
        $("#optionsbox1 .checkbox").addClass('readOnly');
        $(this).parent(".checkbox").removeClass('readOnly');
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
        $("#optionsbox1 :checkbox").removeClass('readOnly');
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting from `$("#optionsbox1 :checkbox")` ??

Comment: That part was working, but that was unchecking the checkbox from the other .checkbox class.  I was able to figure out how to answer my original question with +epascarello's syntax. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what benefit you will get from converting it to one, but the basic idea would use to use not() to remove the element from the collection.

```
var clickedBox = $(this).parent(".checkbox");
var allBoxes = $("#optionsbox1 .checkbox");
allBoxes.not(clickedBox).addClass('readOnly');
```

Another way if `.checkbox` elements are siblings

```
$(this).parent(".checkbox").siblings().addClass('readOnly');
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I was able to figure it out with the syntax your provided, there were multiple parents so I had to alert the syntax a bit but I was able to get it to work and then combined the statement into one line.

Comment: I am not sure what the big deal with one line is. One line does not mean better.  Also there is a better way with one line that does not require not()

Comment: Having multiple statements wasn't that big of a deal, I just didn't want to have two separate statements where first statement was applying that class to all .checkbox and the second one was only there to remove the class from $this parent.

I ended up going with your alternate solution since it didn't use not. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

With +[epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)'s example and a minor change I was able to figure out how to reduce my two statements into one.

Modified version of epascarello's original solution

```
$("#optionsbox1 .checkbox").not($(this).parent('.checkbox')).addClass('readOnly');
```

Epascarello's solution which I ended up using -

```
$(this).parent(".checkbox").siblings(".checkbox").addClass('readOnly');
```